# Grounding the 24 VDC (-)

Tags: power, ground

Does the 24 VDC (-) need to be connected to the ground terminal?

The 24 VDC power supply will supply the PLC, sensors, and PLC I/O terminals.

I made this diagram, just for illustration.

[image]

Comment: A link to the data sheet is needed.

Comment: It depends if you need a floating 24V supply or a ground referenced 24V supply. Might depend on the power supply itself too and there's no data.

Comment: You are thinking (-) always means "ground".   It doesn't.   Sometimes it will, but it doesn't have to.  Sometimes it CAN'T (and you'll explosively find out why if you try it).  As mentioned, need the whole system to make a judgement, not just this snippet

Comment: Where are you getting ground? Do you have a local ground rod/spike in the earth? Are you sure your system wants a negative common?

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for earthing the negative of the 24 V DC power supply in a PLC controlled machine are safety related.

1. The 24 V DC rails, accidentally coming into contact with the mains supply, would expose personnel to the risk of electrocution. In such an event, an earthed 24 V DC negative rail would ensure that the mains supply trips to render the system safe.
2. In the case of frayed cables coming into contact with the machine body, sensor output cables going high at random could cause the machine to malfunction and result in an accident that could endanger operating personnel. Here again an earthed machine body and earthed 24 V DC negative rail would trip the DC power supply and shut down the machine to render it safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you use +24V as PELV (Protective  Extra-Low  Voltage) then according to IEC/EN 60204-1 it should be grounded from one side:

*b)   one  side  of  the  circuit  or  one  point  of  the  source  of  the  supply  of  that  circuit  shall  be connected to the protective bonding circuit;*

Therefore, this is a generally good practice and mandatory if you are controlling some machine and IEC/EN 60204-1 fully applies to your device.

Comment: On the other hand if it is designed as a SELV device it is forbidden to ground either side of the secondary side. Part of the safety of SELV is the tolerance of single insulation failures.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be connect to the net that is elsewhere on this schematic marked with the same symbol.

Whether that includes the terminal that you call "ground terminal" is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/TDR-480/TDR-480-spec.pdf

The power supply is isolated (you can tell by the transformer and optoisolators), isolated supplies can be referenced from different voltages to give different outputs (in this case the 24VDS will be referenced 24V above chassis ground).